# Building interactive form with Contact Form 7 using Ultimate Member value

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, integration

good day to all. I’m using Ultimate Member v2.6.11 (UM) plugin to manage my member registration in my site. I’m thinking of creating an interactive contact form using Contact Form 7 v5.8 (CF7) plugin. I have since been searching throughout the plugin documentary and found totally no idea on how it should be implemented.

I’m not a developer. But I try to explain as clearly as possible on what I want to achieve in the CF7 form below. Sincerely hope that somebody can show me the way to get there:-

```
`<label> 1. Your name </label>
[text your-name default:user_nickname readonly]
// This form-tag fetches & displays logged-in user name from UM user profile. This works well with no issue.

<label> 2. Your email </label>
[email your-email default:user_email readonly]
// This form-tag fetches & displays logged-in user email from UM user profile. This works well with no issue.

<label> 3. Designated member code to which you want to submit this form
[text member-code] </label>
// Here, logged-in user can manually enter the UM member code which is associated with another (logged-out) member.

<label> 4. Moderator’s name </label>
// By entering the member code in item 3 above, I want this field to automatically fetch & display its associated member’s name from the UM user profile. This is the recipient’s name.

<label> 5. Moderator’s email </label>
// By entering the member code in item 3 above, I want this field to automatically fetch & display its associated member’s email from the UM user profile. This is the recipient’s email.`
```

My first question is to solve the issues described in item 4 & 5. I guess this involves some sort of integration between UM & CF7. If they are workable, my second question would be to tackle the CF7 mail-tags for values retrieved in item 4 & 5 so that the form can be submitted to the designated recipient.
Hopefully my question is clear to you.

For your information, here are the UM’s meta keys used in user profile:
Name: nickname
Email: email
Member code: um_unique_account_id

I have tried the codes below given by ChatGPT but it does not work. Perhaps it gives us some clues on how we should achieve the results:

```
`// Hook into Contact Form 7's form submission
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'um_cf7_integration_before_send_mail');

function um_cf7_integration_before_send_mail($contact_form) {
// Get the submitted data
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ($submission) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    // Get the member code from the form submission
    $member_code = sanitize_text_field($posted_data['member-code']);

    // Use the member code to fetch the associated member's name and email from UM
    $user = get_user_by('um_unique_account_id', $member_code);

    if ($user) {
        // Get the name and email from the user
        $moderator_name = $user->display_name;
        $moderator_email = $user->user_email;

        // Update CF7 form fields with the fetched data
        $contact_form->set_properties(array(
            'additional_settings' => "moderator-name:$moderator_name\nmoderator-email:$moderator_email"
        ));
    }
}
```

}`